# Arelle software not installing

Tags: installation, windows-10, xbrl, arelle

I am attempting to install the Arelle XBRL software and these are the steps I am following.

1. Download the Windows 64 bit version from http://arelle.org/pub/applications/
2. Double click on installer

As soon as I click the installer I get an NSIS Error message depicted below.

[image: NSIS Error]

What I have tried:

1. E-mailing the Arelle support dept but they don't seem to answer at all
2. Searched for a solution

The most common solution I have found was to run the installer from the command prompt with the below syntax. This seems to have worked for many people but I am still getting the exact same error.

```
"C:\Users\MyPc\Desktop\arelle-win-x64-2019-07-24.exe" /NCRC
```

This problem has existed for weeks and it doesn't make sense as Arelle is a widely used program for use with XBRL and many people have downloaded it.

Disk checks and various error checks are being done frequently by the company's administrator so computer maintenance is always occurring.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue, I've downloaded installer from another computer and another net, run it on computer where was issue, and it works.